# How to assign a title twice in uibutton

Tags: iphone, ios, uibutton, nsmutablearray

In my application, I have 10 `UIButton`s, and a array of 5 text values. I want to assign each value twice to 10 buttons.?here my code

```
NSString *name;
int value = rand() % ([texts count] -1) ;
for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)view;
        if(button.tag == 1||button.tag == 2||button.tag == 3||button.tag == 4||button.tag == 5||button.tag == 6||button.tag == 7||button.tag == 8||button.tag == 9||button.tag == 10||button.tag == 11||button.tag == 12||button.tag == 13||button.tag == 14||button.tag == 15||button.tag == 16||button.tag == 17||button.tag == 18||button.tag == 19||button.tag == 20)
        {
             name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[texts objectAtIndex:value]];
            [button setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            NSLog(@"current  name :%@",name);
        }
    }
   }
```

but it out puts all buttons having the titile.Please help me to change into only title in two button

Comment: Are the buttons getting added programmatically??

Comment: No.i added in inteface builder @AppleDelegate

Comment: run a loop twice for 10 times.

Comment: you do try anything, till now? paste here your code

Comment: so what actual error you are facing?

Comment: Maybe you should look into ">" and "<" at some point. ;)

Comment: @ForamMukundShah i want to show the 1 title in two buttons,right now all buttons showing the same title

Comment: @ForamMukundShah im asking what change shud i made for that

Answer (score 1):

One tricky way of implementing this would be to tag the UIButtons,if you want the button1 and button2 titles to be same,provide `button1.tag = 1` and `button2.tag = 100` i.e `button2.tag = button1.tag * 100`(Do not start with 0  as tag as 0 is reserved tag of self.view).This can either be done from XIB or programmatically.Further execute the following

```
for (int i = 0 ;i < [array count] ; i++) {
int myTag = i + 1;

UIButton *button1 = [self.view viewWithTag:myTag];
    [button1 setTitle:[array objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIButton *button2 = [self.view viewWithTag:myTag * 100];
    [button2 setTitle:[array objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *texts = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"string 1",@"string 2",@"string 3",@"string 4",@"string 5",nil];
NSArray *buttons = [self.view subviews];
int t=0;
for (int i=0; i<[buttons count]; i++) {
    id view = [buttons objectAtIndex:i];
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *button = (UIButton *)view;
        [button setTitle:[texts objectAtIndex:t/2] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        t++;
    }
}
[texts release];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am just modifying your code, May be this help you, if still any issue, let me know

Thanks

```
int i=1; 
int value = rand() % ([texts count] -1) ;
for(UIView *view in self.view.subviews)
{
    if([view isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]])
    {   

if(button.tag == 1||button.tag == 2||button.tag == 3||button.tag == 4||button.tag == 5||button.tag == 6||button.tag == 7||button.tag == 8||button.tag == 9||button.tag == 10||button.tag == 11||button.tag == 12||button.tag == 13||button.tag == 14||button.tag == 15||button.tag == 16||button.tag == 17||button.tag == 18||button.tag == 19||button.tag == 20)
    {
      int myTag= i+1;  
      UIButton *button1 = [self.view viewWithTag:myTag]; 
      name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[texts objectAtIndex:value]];
       [button1 setTitle:name forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        NSLog(@"current  name :%@",name);
    }
     i++;
}
```

Comment: it works but its showing ,some items 2 times ,some other items 3,4 times,What should i do

Comment: yes I know, this is because your rand() method. tell me, how many times you wants same text on buttons. describe it

Comment: i want 2 times,that is, 1 title in 2 buttons randomly